# How do I implement a DFA in Java without using reg expression?

Tags: java, finite-automata, state-machine, dfa, states

I have this input file :

```
2
4
ab
1 0 2 0 3 0 3 3
0
1 3
aaa
bbaaab
abab
zzz
7
ab
2 1 3 0 4 3 5 2 6 5 6 4 6 6
0
1 5
a
aab
baa
bbabbabbb
ababb
ababba
zzz
```

The first line represents the number of test cases.

Each test case starts with 3 integers, the first is the number of state for the automaton, next is the number of symbols in the alphabet and then the number of final states.

The next line is the alphabet. The symbols appear together.

Next is an arbitrary number of lines containing inputs over Σ(alphabet). Each input is a string of characters taken from Σ(alphabet).

The lines of input are terminated by a final line containing the string zzz.

my output should look like this

```
DMA M1
aaa: Accepted
bbaaab: Accepted
abab: Rejected

DMA M2
a: Rejected
aab: Accepted
baa: Accepted
bbabbabbb: Accepted
ababb: Accepted
ababba: Rejected
```

Here is my code thus far :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class DFAImplementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //create the file instance
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("DFA.txt");
        //it's scanner time
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        //read it
        int dfaAmount = input.nextInt();
        //loop for amount of dfas
       for (int dfaAmountIndex = 0; dfaAmountIndex < dfaAmount;
                dfaAmountIndex++){
            int numberOfStates = input.nextInt();
            int startState;
            int numberOfSigmaSym;



            String sigma = "";
            sigma = input.next();


            numberOfSigmaSym = sigma.length();
            String transitionLine = input.nextLine();
            int[][] transition = new int[numberOfStates][numberOfSigmaSym];


            startState = input.nextInt();    
            //checker
            System.out.println(startState);
            int i;
            int j;
            for (i=0; i < numberOfStates; i++){
                numberOfStates = i;
                numberOfSigmaSym = j;
                for (j=0; j < sigma.length(); j++){
            int state1 = transition[i][j];
                }
        }

            String w;
            w = input.nextLine();
            for (i=0; i < w.length(); i++){

                 char x;
               x = w.charAt(i);
               int state = startState;
                int index = sigma.indexOf(x);
                int state1 = transition [state][index];
            }
            int numberOfAcceptStates;
            numberOfAcceptStates = input.nextInt();
            int acceptState;
            acceptState = input.nextInt();





         // if(){

          }
      //    else(){
       }

    }

//}
```

--Edit: Basically I just don't know what to do with my transition array and states.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: @Henry, I'm confused on what to do with the transition array. Do I keep making multiple States and set that to transition?

Comment: How is the transition array suppose to be read? Is it a set of pairs representing the next state for the alaphet over the number of states?

ie;
{{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}}
So state 0, a -> 1, b -> 0
state 1, a-> 2, b -> 0
etc ? 
The file description also doesn't seem to fit the file.

Comment: @Doswell , Are you talking about the fourth line? That's the States. so 0 would be the first state, 1 would be the second. Then the alphabet given would be over those states.

Comment: ok so it is the transitions, as looking at the first example starting at 0 for aaa would move as;
0 (a)-> 1 (a)-> 2 (a)-> 3

and 3 is a valid end state,
similar for bbaaab;

0 (b)-> 0 (b)-> 0 (a)-> 1 (a)-> 2 (a)-> 3 (b)-> 3
So it might be easier to read the states into an object which has an array or hashtable of the alphabet and the next state that letter goes to. Than for each letter in the line move to the next state, ie;
int currentState = 0;
for (i=0; i<w.length();i++)
  currentState = states[currentState].nextState(w.charAt(i))

Where states is something like;
State[] states;

Comment: And State is something like;
Hashtable<Integer, Integer> nextStates; 
public int nextState(char letter) {
  return nextStates.get(Integer.valueOf(letter));
}

Answer (score -1):

looking at the first example starting at 0 for aaa would move as; 
0 (a)-> 1 (a)-> 2 (a)-> 3 and 3 is a valid end state, similar for bbaaab; 
0 (b)-> 0 (b)-> 0 (a)-> 1 (a)-> 2 (a)-> 3 (b)-> 3

So it might be easier to read the states into an object which has an array or hashtable of the alphabet and the next state that letter goes to.

Than for each letter in the line move to the next state, ie;

```
 int currentState = 0; 
for (i=0; i<w.length();i++) 
    currentState = states[currentState].nextState(w.charAt(i))
```

Where states is something like;

```
State[] states;
```

And State is something like;

```
Hashtable<Integer, Integer> nextStates;
 public int nextState(char letter) { 
    return nextStates.get(Integer.valueOf(letter));
 }
```

Then after check if current state is a valid end state.

Comment: For integer valueof(letter) might need to be calurif((int)letter)